# How to compile c++ code that uses recursive variadic templates with icpc17?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, icc

I want to compile a variadic template based version of a matrix vector product with the icpc 17 compiler (`icpc (ICC) 17.0.4 20170411`). The code compiles without any issues both with clang and gcc. However, with icpc the compilation seems to hang (I waited for about an hour).
Does anybody know of a documented bug of icpc I'm encountering here and if so has someone an idea how to circumvent this bug?

```
#ifndef UTILS_MATRIX_VECTOR_PRODUCT_HPP
#define UTILS_MATRIX_VECTOR_PRODUCT_HPP

#include <array>
#include <utility>

namespace Utils {

namespace detail {

template <int c, typename T> struct mul {
  constexpr T operator()(const T a) const { return c * a; }
};

template <typename T> struct mul<0, T> {
  constexpr T operator()(const T a) const { return T{}; }
};

template <typename T> struct mul<1, T> {
  constexpr T operator()(const T a) const { return a; }
};

template <int I, typename T, std::size_t N, int c, int... cs>
struct inner_product_template_impl {
  constexpr T operator()(std::array<T, N> const &a) const {
    return mul<c, T>{}(std::get<I>(a)) +
           inner_product_template_impl<I + 1, T, N, cs...>{}(a);
  }
};

template <int I, typename T, std::size_t N, int c>
struct inner_product_template_impl<I, T, N, c> {
  constexpr T operator()(std::array<T, N> const &a) const {
    return mul<c, T>{}(std::get<I>(a));
  }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N,
          const std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> &matrix,
          std::size_t row_index, std::size_t... column_indices>
constexpr T inner_product_helper(const std::array<T, N> &vec,
                                 std::index_sequence<column_indices...>) {
  return inner_product_template_impl<
      0, T, N, std::get<column_indices>(std::get<row_index>(matrix))...>{}(vec);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N,
          const std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> &matrix,
          std::size_t row_index>
constexpr T inner_product_template(const std::array<T, N> &vec) {
  return detail::inner_product_helper<T, N, matrix, row_index>(
      vec, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N,
          const std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> &matrix,
          std::size_t... column_indices>
constexpr std::array<T, N>
matrix_vector_product_helper(const std::array<T, N> &vec,
                             std::index_sequence<column_indices...>) {
  return std::array<T, N>{
      {inner_product_template<T, N, matrix, column_indices>(vec)...}};
}

} // namespace detail

template <typename T, std::size_t N,
          const std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> &matrix>
constexpr std::array<T, N> matrix_vector_product(const std::array<T, N> &vec) {
  return detail::matrix_vector_product_helper<T, N, matrix>(
      vec, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

} // namespace Utils

#endif
```

For a working example, the following source file can be used:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#include "matrix_vector_product.hpp"

static constexpr const std::array<std::array<int, 19>, 19>
    matrix =
    {{{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
      {{0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1}},
      {{-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
      {{0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1}},
      {{-0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1}},
      {{0, -2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
      {{0, 0, 0, -2, 2, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1}},
      {{0, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
      {{0, 0, 0, -0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1}},
      {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1}},
      {{1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
      {{0, -1, -1, 1, 1, -0, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1}},
      {{0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}}}};

int main() {
    std::array<double, 19> vector{{4,3,5,2,3,4,5,6,6,4,24,7,8,2,3,9,2,32,2}};
    auto const result = Utils::matrix_vector_product<double, 19, matrix>(vector);
    for (auto const& res : result) {
        std::cout << res << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile with

```
icpc -std=c++14 main.cpp
```

Comment: Can you share with us a minimal, contained, reproducible code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I updated the question and added some usage example.

Comment: BTW: I just tried the very same thing with `icpc (ICC) 18.0.1 20171018` and it works.

Comment: It seems a dubious practice to name a variable vector.  I had to read it a few times to realize it was a variable name, and not std::vector.  My gut instinct is that you should give feedback to Intel on this.